# not getting output but they do not show error

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random


dict = {0:'rock',1:'Spock',2:'paper',3:'lizard',4:'scissors'}


def name_to_number(name):

    if name == "rock":
        return 0
    elif name == "spock":
        return 1
    elif name == "paper":
        return 2
    elif name == "lizard":
        return 3
    elif name == "csissors":
        return 4
    else:
        print("error:wrong name!")
        return

def number_to_name(number):

    if number == 0:
        return "rock"
    elif number == 1:
        return "spock"
    elif number == 2:
        return "paper"
    elif number == 3:
        return "lizard"
    elif number == 4:
        return "scissors"
    else:
        print("error: wrong number!")
        return


def rpsls(palyer_choice):
    print(" ")
    print("players chooses %s",'player_choice')

    player_number = name_to_number(player_choice)
    comp_number = random.randrange(0, 5)
    print ("Computer chooses %s",' comp_number')


    difference = player_number - comp_number
    if difference == 0:
        print("Player and computer tie!")
    elif difference == 3 or difference ==3 or difference == -1 or difference == -2:
         print ("computer wins!")
    else:
         print("Players wins!")
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to call `rpsls` function

so add this code in the last of your code

`rpsls()`